Confusion about Left split implying a direct product of groups
I was doing a homework problem that has a left split exact sequence $$ 1 \to H \xrightarrow{i} G \xrightarrow{\pi} G/H \to 1,$$ ($H$ is a subgroup of $G$, $i$ is the inclusion map). Assume we have a retraction $r:G \to H$ that is a left inverse of $i$, and I was asked to establish the isomorphisms $G\simeq H\times \ker(r)$ and $\ker (r)\simeq G/H$.
I tried to establish an explicit isomorphism $G/H\to \ker(r)$ by sending $gH$ to $g^{-1}i(r(g))$, since $g^{-1}i(r(g))$ is always in ker($r$). I showed that it is well defined for different representitives of the cosets but I cannot show that it is actually a group homomorphism.
So my plan of giving an isomorphism $G\simeq H\times \ker(r)$  by $g\to (r(g),g^{-1}i(r(g)))$ fails; I cannot show that it is a group homomorphism and I also cant see why the ker($r$) component is surjective.
This question had a previous part where I showed the exact sequence split on the right implies $G$ is a semidirect product. This allowed me to establish $G$ as a semidirect product of $H$ and ker($r$), (and since they are normal in $G$ it is a direct product), but this still doesn't tell me how to find the isomorphism $\ker(r)\simeq G/H$.
I told all these to my professor and was told that I was overthinking and could just use the a criterion for internal direct product. (I think he meant if $N,H\mathrel{\unlhd} G$; $N,H$ intersect trivially and $G=NH$ we get a direct product). But I don't see how to get from this to the isomorphism $\ker(r)\simeq G/H$ since even if $G\simeq H\times \ker(r)$ and $G\simeq H\times N$ doesn't nessearily mean that $\ker(r)≃G/H$. Is it just as simple as because ker($r$)=$(N\times \ker(r))/\ker(r)$?
Also, why does my arguments fail exactly (beside the point that G might not be commutative)? Also, how do I get an explicit isomorphism $\ker(r)≃G/H$ (or an explicit $G\simeq H\times \ker(r)$)?
Any input greatly appreciated!

Is "$r$" supposed to be the name of the retraction $G\to H$ to the embedding? It would be clearer if you actually labeled your maps so it is apparent what maps you are talking about. Also, make sure your parentheses are balanced. $g^{-1}i(r(g)$ has one too many left parentheses, or one too few right ones.

Sorry, I edited to clarify.

Your argument fails because you are mapping to the wrong thing. You shouldn't map $gH$ to $g^{-1}i(r(g))$; you should map it to $gi(r(g^{-1}))$. You are composing what is the correct isomorphism with the inversion map, but the inversion map may not be an automorphism for nonabelian $G$, and that is where the problem lies.

Ah, thank you. For some reason I thought since $g^{-1}i(r(g))$ didn't work, $gi(r(g^{-1}))$ also wouldn't..

Suppose we have
$$1\to H\stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow}G\stackrel{\pi}{\longrightarrow} G/H \to 1$$
a short exact sequence, and a morphism $r\colon G\to H$ such that $ri=\mathrm{id}_H$. You want to show that $G\cong H\times\ker(r)$ and that $\ker(r)\cong G/H$.
The fact that $G\cong H\times \ker(r)$ follows from the following observations:

$i(H)\triangleleft G$, because this is a short exact sequence.
$\ker(r)\triangleleft G$ because it is the kernel of a homomorphism.
$\ker(r)\cap i(H)=\{e\}$ because if $x\in\ker(r)\cap i(H)$, then $x =i(h)$ for some unique $h\in H$, so $e = r(x) = r(i(h)) = h$, hence $x=i(h)=i(e)=e$.
$\ker(r)i(H)=G$. Indeed, let $g\in G$; now consider $x=gi(r(g^{-1}))$; this element lies in $\ker(r)$, since
$$r(x) = r(gi(r(g^{-1}))) = r(g)r(i(r(g^{-1}))) = r(g)r(g^{-1}) = r(g)r(g)^{-1}=e,$$
because $r(i(h)) = h$ for all $h\in H$, in particular for $h=r(g^{-1})$. And $g=xi(r(g))$, since $i(r(g^{-1}))i(r(g))=e$. Thus, $g \in \ker(r)i(H)$, proving that $G\subseteq \ker(r)i(H)$, which gives equality.

This proves that $G= \ker(r)\times i(H)\cong H\times \ker(r)$.
To prove that $\ker(r)\cong G/H$ we verify that $\pi|_{\ker(r)}$ is an isomorphism. Indeed, if $g\in G$, then we already saw above that $g=xi(r(g))$ with $x=gi(r(g^{-1}))\in\ker(r)$. Now note that $\pi(i(r(g)))=1$ because the sequence is exact, so $\pi(g) = \pi(x)$. That is, for every $g\in G$ there exists $x\in\ker(r)$ such that $\pi(g)=\pi(x)$. That tells you that the image of $\pi|_{\ker(r)}$ equals the image of $\pi$, which is all of $G/H$, so the restriction of $\pi$ to $\ker(r)$ is surjective. And since the kernel of $\pi$ is $i(H)$, and $i(H)\cap \ker(r)=\{e\}$, then $\pi|_{\ker(r)}$ is one-to-one. Thus, $\pi|_{\ker(r)}$ is an isomorphism from $\ker(r)$ to $G/H$, which is what we needed to show.

This is a standard question that has appeared at least 10 times on the site. Please don't answer duplicate questions. This is against site policy, see here.

Sorry, I've seen these posts, but they didn't answer my question and I was still confused after seeing them. That's why I was asking for an explicit isomorphism.

@DailinLi: If you have seen other posts in the site that seem to address your query but you are still confused, then you need to refer to them explicitly in your post and specify why they are still confusing. Ideally, though, you would first post those queries as comments in the answers, at least if they are recent enough to believe their owners are still around and active.
